# Highcharts - how can I change font size?

Tags: css, highcharts

I need to change font size in cloud on highchart.
How to do it?

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                color: '#FF00FF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/autrmg62/

Screen:

[image: Screen]

Comment: Consider format your question in a more usable way.

Comment: @knitevision, what do not you understand?

Comment: @Piszu: One problem was that the links you provided were not correctly formatted, so you couldn't click the links to follow them. Another problem was that it is not a good style to link to external sources only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/autrmg62/2/)

My custom code has been used on lines 4-12.

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 20px; color: red;">{point.key}</span><br/>',
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '13px'
    }     
},
```

Styling of the element you wanted was accomplished by `headerFormat` and specifying styles you want in the `style=""`

Have a look at: **[Highchart API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.headerFormat)**